# Promise set right(?) but not always working -- JavaScript in Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase

Is this promise set right?  It works 99% of the time but it is possible that every once in a while it does not write the value.  I'm guessing it is because I have so many variables being written.  Should I change return null to return dbwritedata2 or something?

```js
async function dbwrite2() {
    try {
        dbwritedata2 = {
            a: a,
            pb: pb,
            pn: pn,
            po: po,
            q: q,
            qref: qref,
            s: s,
            t: t,
            tb: tb,
            tn: tn,
            to: to,
            type1: type1,
        };

        dbwritedata3 = {
            epsilon: epsilon,
        };

        let setDoc2 = db
            .collection('qtable')
            .doc('qtable')
            .collection(pass)
            .doc(docnametemp)
            .set(dbwritedata2);
        let setDoc3 = db
            .collection('qtable')
            .doc('qtable')
            .collection(pass)
            .doc('ref')
            .update(dbwritedata3)
            //update epsilon (above)
            //this step and all others needs to be moved

            .then((doc) => {
                return null;
            });

        //  })
        // do stuff
        console.log('do stuff');
    } catch (e) {
        // error!
    }
    return null;
} //end dbwrite2

return dbwrite2().then(function(response) {
    rr = 'done';

    res.status(200).send(rr);
});
```

Comment: You are not awaiting firebase functions to finish. Shouldn't `db.collectio....` be `await db.collectio....`?

Comment: Thanks I added that and my initial test seems to work